# Few files upload from device to server out of pushed list

Tags: java, android, file-upload, server

I wrote two different code to try to upload selected files to server, but none of them is uploaded all the files available in list though both codes show uploading complete without any error.  pls help to fix it.

```
Thread up = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            String content_type = getMimeType(filespath.get(ina));
                                            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                                            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type), new File(filespath.get(ina)));


                                            RequestBody requestBody1 = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                                                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                                                    .addFormDataPart("type", content_type)
                                                    .addFormDataPart("myFile", filespath.get(ina).substring(filespath.get(ina).lastIndexOf("/") + 1), requestBody)
                                                    .addFormDataPart("location", titlevalue + "/")
                                                    .build();

                                            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("MyPHP URL")
                                                    .post(requestBody1)
                                                    .build();
                                            try {
                                                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                                                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Log.i(TAG, "Error");
                                                }
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                    up.start();
```

filespath is String Arraylist with path of all files being uploaded and this Thread is called in Forloop of same.

Other method tried is as follows:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                                            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(filespath.get(ina)));
                                            multipartEntity.addPart("myFile", fileBody);
                                            multipartEntity.addTextBody("location", titlevalue + "/");

                                            HttpEntity httpEntity = multipartEntity.build();

                                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("MyPHP URL");
                                            httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);

                                            try {
                                                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Http Re" + httpResponse);
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
```

I did few trials to check like when I selected only 20 Images, all uploaded and I got ok response too. Where as when I tried with 40 images, I could upload only 32 with ok response, where as for remaining 8, there was no response.
pls guide, what I m missing.[image: Logcat]

See Logcat 9 files uploaded where as on server I found only 4. (numbered 1,2,3,4)

Comment: Maybe the issue is on server side, if server doesn't except videos which are grater than certain size.

Comment: all videos are of upto 2 mb as if I send only videos, sometimes it upload all 5 too.